colcon build failed in examples_rclpy_* , when I tried to build according to ros2 tutorial
I'm trying to follow the tutorials for working with ROS2 jazzy in Ubuntu24.04.1 LTS.
I got examples src from github and executed colcon build according to 'Build the workspace'.
Then the following warning occurred in "examples_rclpy_*" and "launch_testing_examples".
Could you help me?
Warning message sample.
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_executors
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:261:
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'  
warnings.warn(msg)
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_executors 
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:261:
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'  
warnings.warn(msg)
--- Finished <<< examples_rclpy_executors [0.92s]

Of cource, 'colcon test' failed in "examples_rclpy_*" and "launch_testing_examples".
I had already installed pytest 8.3.4, because the following code in 'setup.py'.
But these failed didn't resolve.
    license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],


How did you install ROS 2?
This is caused by setuptools version mismatch.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295644/pypi-userwarning-unknown-distribution-option-install-requires

Thx Ryan.
I installed ROS2 by according to install guide.
sudo apt install ros-jazzy-desktop
But I forgot how install setuptools.
Now my setuptools version is 75.6.0.
How version does it match to ROS 2 jazzy?

It looks like you may have installed setuptools through pip as user, with the latest version, on top of the one installed by ros-jazzy-desktop, which is managed by apt.
Using docker, I can show you what's installed by default in a clean Jazzy environment:
First, start the image:
docker run

Here's how you can see the version installed by ros-jazzy-desktop:
# apt show python3-setuptools
Package: python3-setuptools
Version: 68.1.2-2ubuntu1.1
Priority: optional
Section: python
Source: setuptools
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 2286 kB
Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 68.1.2-2ubuntu1.1), python3:any
Suggests: python-setuptools-doc
Homepage: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
Task: cloud-image, cloud-image, ubuntu-wsl, server, ubuntu-server-raspi, ubuntustudio-photography, ubuntustudio-publishing, edubuntu-desktop-gnome, edubuntu-desktop-gnome-raspi
Download-Size: 396 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: Python3 Distutils Enhancements

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

Now, in docker, check what pip has installed. I expect your computer is reporting as 75.6.0.
$ apt update
# Note - the docker image doesn't contain pip
$ apt install python3-pip
# Now, with pip, show which version of setuptools the python interpreter would use
$ python3 -m pip show setuptools
Name: setuptools
Version: 68.1.2
Summary: Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
Home-page: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
Author: Python Packaging Authority
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: 
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: action-tutorials-py, ament-copyright, ament-cppcheck, ament-cpplint, ament-flake8, ament-index-python, ament-lint, ament-lint-cmake, ament-pep257, ament-uncrustify, ament-xmllint, catkin-pkg-modules, colcon-core, colcon-python-setup-py, demo-nodes-py, domain-coordinator, examples-rclpy-executors, examples-rclpy-minimal-action-client, examples-rclpy-minimal-action-server, examples-rclpy-minimal-client, examples-rclpy-minimal-publisher, examples-rclpy-minimal-service, examples-rclpy-minimal-subscriber, launch, launch-ros, launch-testing, launch-testing-ros, launch-xml, launch-yaml, quality-of-service-demo-py, rosdistro-modules, rosidl-pycommon, rqt-action, rqt-bag, rqt-bag-plugins, rqt-console, rqt-graph, rqt-gui, rqt-gui-py, rqt-msg, rqt-plot, rqt-publisher, rqt-py-console, rqt-reconfigure, rqt-service-caller, rqt-shell, rqt-srv, rqt-topic, sensor-msgs-py, sros2, teleop-twist-keyboard, tf2-ros-py, tf2-tools, topic-monitor

If you want to undo this user install, just run the following in your environment:
python3 -m pip uninstall setuptools

This would uninstall the pip managed one in ~/.local, but the one installed by apt is still there:
python3 -m pip show setuptools

I expect now you will have the right version.
For more info on uninstalling user versions to stop overriding the one managed by apt, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524522/11032285
Running python3 -m pip install setuptools, or perhaps an install of a python package that depends on setuptools is a really easy way to break your ROS installation. If you need to install python packages that depend on setuptools and want to preserve your ROS environment, I recommend installing these other packages in virtual environments.

I had made a duplicate of 'setuptools' in localy, and there was no path through to
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'.
I could get fine result to remove 'pip uninstall setuptools' and add the pass.
@Ryan THX!
